# SQL query error unknown column in SELECT + JOIN +

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my SQL code (using phpmyadmin simulator) :

```
SELECT user_activity.user_ip,user_activity.id,user_activity.post_id , posts.id
FROM  user_activity,users 
INNER JOIN posts ON user_activity.post_id = posts.id
WHERE user_activity.user_id = users.id and users.forgen_note = 'test note';
```

And it respons an error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'user_activity_now.stream_id' in 'on clause'
```

How can I fix it please?

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN` clause between `user_activity` and `users`. Removed SQL Server tag. Obviously MySQL.

Comment: You have an extra implicit join using a very old syntax `FROM user_activity, users` then you have a second `INNER JOIN` using the accepted syntax after.

Comment: user_activity_now isn't mentioned in the query. Which means that you're either accessing views, or you haven't placed the correct query or error message.

Comment: @WEI_DBA you mean like this: "FROM  user_activity INNER JOIN posts ON user_activity.post_id = posts.id users "  ??

Comment: @JacobH Could you tell me how can I fix my query by example?

Comment: Dude, there is no fix anyone can give you unless you provide the table definitions of the tables you're querying. You'll likely find that one of them is not a table at all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix join syntax:

```
SELECT user_activity.user_ip,user_activity.id,user_activity.post_id, posts.id
FROM user_activity
    INNER JOIN users ON user_activity.user_id = users.id
    INNER JOIN posts ON user_activity.post_id = posts.id
WHERE users.forgen_note = 'test note';
```

Generally you should avoid using comma joins.  It's harder to read and is less expressive overall about what you're doing.